# Enviar correo electrónico formato html con android estudio

Tags: android-studio, android-intent

Querría saber como puedo enviar un correo electrónico en formato html mediante android studio.

Este es el método que he creado. Lo importante está en el intent.

```
public void enviarEmail() {

         checkEmail email = new checkEmail();
         String[] emailsEnvio = email.obtenerEmailEnvios(f_carpetaAPP,nombreUsuario);

        String mensajeCuerpo ="";

        if (emailsEnvio.length==0) {

            Intent i = new Intent(MenuLog_Activity.this,popUPMensaje.class);
            i.putExtra("usuario",nombreUsuario);
            i.putExtra("mensaje",getString(R.string.noAdress));
            startActivity(i);

        } else  {

            mensajeCuerpo = crearCuerpoCorreo(f_carpetaAPP,nombreUsuario);
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
            i.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,emailsEnvio);
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,getString(R.string.Extra_Subject)+ " " +nombreUsuario);
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,mensajeCuerpo);
            startActivity(i);

        }

    }
```

Llevo tiempo buscando información si bien es cierto que hay, pero no consigo hacer que funcione.

Si alguien puede ayudarme lo agradecería.

Saludos,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para renderizar el contenido HTML necesitas usar el método `fromHtml()` de [la clase `Html`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html), pasándole en parámetro el texto con etiquetas HTML adecuadas.

Dado que `fromHtml()` tiene problemas de compatibilidad, es mejor crear un método desde el cual gestiones esos problemas.

En la respuesta lo pondré como un método en tu contexto:

```
private Spanned fromHtml(String inputText) {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        return Html.fromHtml(inputText, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
    } else {
        return Html.fromHtml(inputText);
    }
}
```

Para usarlo, pasas `mensajeCuerpo` en parámetro al método:

```
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,fromHtml(mensajeCuerpo));
```

Asumo que `mensajeCuerpo` está etiquetado adecuadamente.

Sin embargo, si necesitas formatear HTML desde otros puntos de tu aplicación, considera crear una clase utilitaria y declarar el método como  `public static`.

Por ejemplo:

```
public static Spanned fromHtml(String inputText) {
    /*
       Este if es para manejar el caso de deprecated
       Ver: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37904739/html-fromhtml-deprecated-in-android-n
    */
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        return Html.fromHtml(inputText, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
    } else {
        return Html.fromHtml(inputText);
    }
}
```

En este caso, suponiendo que la clase declarada se llama `Utils` y es estática, la llamada sería así:

```
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,Utils.fromHtml(mensajeCuerpo));
```

#### Nota importante

Considera que la App de Gmail de Android no permite enviar mensajes con contenido HTML, y es posible que otras Apps similares tampoco. Sea como sea, dado que la inmensa mayoría de dispositivos Android traen por defecto la App de Gmail como aplicación por defecto para el envío de correos, no tendría sentido programar un código que no funcionará en la mayoría de los casos.

No obstante, puede que haya alternativas. Se me ocurre conectar la App de Android con Google Apps Script, para así generar y enviar el email desde ese entorno, donde sí es permitido mandar correos con contenido HTML. [Este puede ser un punto de partida](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/quickstart/java) si te interesa explorar esa opción. Las posibilidades son enormes si conectas ambas herramientas, ya que desde Google Apps Script puedes programar envíos y cosas por el estilo.

Comment: Muchas gracias Cedano, estoy implementando el código. pero no me funciona al menos los colores y estilos en los textos.```<string name="valorLineaAzucar"><![CDATA[<b><font color="red">Avg. Value (in 30 days) :</font></b>]]></string>```Los añado al string dado que la aplicación la creo en dos idiomas

Comment: @joserodriguezan ¿en las pruebas que App estás usando para enviar el email? [Según se dice aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51745104/5587982) la App de Gmail tiene capada la composición de mensajes con contenido HTML, debes probar con otra App de envío de email que permita enviar `text/html`. Sea como sea, dado que la mayoría de dispositivos Android usan Gmail, tiene poca utilidad querer enviar contenido con formato HTML sabiendo que en muchos casos no va a funcionar.

Comment: No me acordaba de las limitaciones de gmail. Una pena. Por desgracia  quiero que la aplicación pueda enviar datos a través del correo del usuario y Android gmail es lo común.  Muchas gracias.

Comment: @joserodriguezan puede que haya alternativas. Se me ocurre conectar la App de Android con Google Apps Script, para así generar y enviar el email desde ese entorno, donde sí es permitido mandar correos con contenido HTML. [Este puede ser un punto de partida](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/quickstart/java). Las posibilidades son enormes si conectas ambas herramientas, desde Google Apps Script puedes programar envíos y cosas por el estilo.